# Trying to find the last time that a value has changed in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `Document` table:

```
| ID|   DOC_ID     | Count|
  1       22           1
  2       22           1
  3       22           2
  4       22           2
  5       22           2
  6       22           3
```

Can I write a SQL query that will only return the latest rows in where a count change occurs? I'm using SQL Server

Desired output :

```
ID    DOC_ID   Count
---------------------
6       22      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(count) over (partition by doc_id order by id) as prev_count
      from t
     ) t
where prev_count <> count;
```

This is more painful in SQL Server 2008.  I would recommend `apply`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, tprev.count as prev_count
      from t cross apply
           (select top (1) tprev.*
            from t tprev
            where tprev.doc_id = t.doc_id and tprev.id < t.id
            order by tprev.id desc
           ) tprev
     ) t
where prev_count <> count;
```

The subquery is not necessary for this version.  I just put it there so you can see the relationship between the two queries.  This works just as well:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.doc_id = t.doc_id and tprev.id < t.id
      order by tprev.id desc
     ) tprev
where tprev.count <> t.count;
```

I can also add that if you know that the counts never change back, then you can get the first `id` for each one using aggregation:

```
select doc_id, count, min(id) as min(id)
from t
group by doc_id, count;
```

Under many circumstances, this will be faster than the `apply` version (although the `lag()` would often have the best performance).

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion

Comment: @Jeswanth . . . As the OP, you can accept whatever answer you like.  But is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?